# How to get max() to return the first and second highest value in priority

Tags: python, list, max

I'm working on a personality system for my game. Basically I'm trying to return the two highest values in a list without altering the list.

```
social_sum = 0
morals_sum = 0
perception_sum = 0
boldness_sum = 0
for trait in self.traits:
    for personality in trait.personality:
        social_sum += personality.social
        morals_sum += personality.morals
        perception_sum += personality.perception
        boldness_sum += personality.boldness
                
personality_list = [social_sum, morals_sum, perception_sum, boldness_sum]
```

There are 4 types of personalities (which may be positive or negative). The top two highest absolute values of those personalities will determine the persona of a character.

I've tried manually by using `remove()` and then doing the `max()` function again to return the second highest value. But that will alter `personality_list` and create other problems down the line. Here's my code, sorry if it looks really repetitive as I'm still learning the ropes.

```
print(personality_list)
personality_list = [abs(social_sum), abs(morals_sum), abs(perception_sum), abs(boldness_sum)]
print(personality_list)
first_personality = max(personality_list)

for fp in personality_list:
    if first_personality == social_sum:
        fp = "Extrovert"
    elif -first_personality == social_sum:
        fp = "Introvert"
    elif first_personality == morals_sum:
        fp = "Idealist"
    elif -first_personality == morals_sum:
        fp = "Pragmatic"
    elif first_personality == perception_sum:
        fp = "Upright"
    elif -first_personality == perception_sum:
        fp = "Relaxed"
    elif first_personality == boldness_sum:
        fp = "Dominant"
    elif -first_personality == boldness_sum:
        fp = "Submissive"

print(fp)
personality_list.remove(first_personality)
print(personality_list)

second_personality = max(personality_list)

for sp in personality_list:
    if second_personality == social_sum:
        sp = "Extrovert"
    elif -second_personality == social_sum:
        sp = "Introvert"
    elif second_personality == morals_sum:
        sp = "Idealist"
    elif -second_personality == morals_sum:
        sp = "Pragmatic"
    elif second_personality == perception_sum:
        sp = "Upright"
    elif -second_personality == perception_sum:
        sp = "Relaxed"
    elif second_personality == boldness_sum:
        sp = "Dominant"
    elif -second_personality == boldness_sum:
        sp = "Submissive"
        
print(sp)
```

If the numbers align correctly the code works. Here is an example of the output:

```
[-35, -25, 10, 10]
[35, 25, 10, 10]
Introvert
[25, 10, 10]
Pragmatic
```

If there are two second highest numbers, the output still prioritize the list's index, which is what I want:

```
[5, 0, 35, -5]
[5, 0, 35, 5]
Upright
[5, 0, 5]
Extrovert
```

But if there are two equal absolute highest numbers, the indices obtained through `max`ing the output while `remove`ing the one already used will not be correct:

```
[-5, -20, 20, 5]
[5, 20, 20, 5]
Upright
[5, 20, 5]
Upright
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sort the list and extract the last 2 elements (or first depending on your requirement). Use *sorted()* which will not affect your original list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution with sorting the list would be

```py
from typing import List

personalities: List[List[str]] = [
    ["Extrovert", "Introvert"],
    ["Idealist", "Pragmatic"],
    ["Upright", "Relaxed"],
    ["Dominant", "Submissive"]
]

score: List[int] = [-5, -20, 20, 5]
sorted_indices: List[int] = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(score), key=lambda k: abs(k[1]), reverse=True)]
for i in range(2): # Number of traits neeeded
    index: int = sorted_indices[i]
    secondary_index: int = 0
    if score[index] < 0:
        secondary_index = 1
    print(p[index][secondary_index])
```

Here, we get the indexes of the values in the order they would be in a sorted score list, without modifying the list itself, so it shouldn't impact the program down the line.
The sorting takes place at the declaration of `sorted_indices` and proceeds as follows: a list of pairs index, value is generated (`enumerate(score)`), then sorted in reverse according to the absolute value  (`sorted(enumerate(score), key=lambda k: abs(k[1]), reverse=True)`), and finally we get rid of the value part, for we only need the indices (`i[0] for i in ...`).

---

Edit: to make a list out of the selected personnalities

```py
from typing import List

personalities: List[List[str]] = [
    ["Extrovert", "Introvert"],
    ["Idealist", "Pragmatic"],
    ["Upright", "Relaxed"],
    ["Dominant", "Submissive"]
]
selected_personalities: List[str] = []

score: List[int] = [-5, -20, 20, 5]
sorted_indices: List[int] = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(score), key=lambda k: abs(k[1]), reverse=True)]
for i in range(2): # Number of traits neeeded
    index: int = sorted_indices[i]
    secondary_index: int = 0
    if score[index] < 0:
        secondary_index = 1
    selected_personalities.append(personalities[index][secondary_index])

print(selected_personalities)
```

Comment: Sorry to ask again. But how do you make a set out of the two selected personalities using this method?

Comment: I've edited the post, it should answer your question. In the edit, I've assumed you wanted a `list` rather than a `set`, for you might need to know which trait is the primary/secondary one. A Python `list` is an ordered collection of objects, while a `set` is an un-ordered one.

Comment: Nice. Once again, many thanks.